# use unordered_set<T> or unordered_set<T*>?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

If we use `unordered_set<T>` (`T` is custom type, not simple type), it's quite likely that we need define custom `operator==` and  hasher, which is kind of cumbersome if we have lots of different `T` in a big project. Furthermore how to choose a good hash function is a big issue.

But if we use `unordered_set<T*>` (including smart pointer), we can omit those definitions. Especially I find in rocksdb and mysql-server codebase, lots of `unordered_set<T*>` are used instead of `unordered_set<T>`, whereas in mongodb and scylladb, lots of `unordered_set<T>` defined. This situation gives me impression that rocksdb developers seems intentionally to avoid using `unordered_set<T>` ?

So I'm a little confused when to use `unordered_set<T>` and when use `unorderd_set<T*>` ?

Comment: If you use `unordered_set<T*>` you will have the set store pointers and the objects stored somewhere else, hence using up more memory.

Comment: If you have two objects of type T, which are identical, but exist in two separate places in memory, then `unordered_set<T*>` will **not** consider them the same, since they have difference addresses.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly (I'm a little rusty on C/++ terms), it's likely that the `unordered_set<T*>` uses reference equality (and the address as a hash) in order to determine equality within the sets. If you have values that should overwrite for separate objects, `<T*>` won't work.

Comment: whereas `42 == 42`,  `new int(42) != new int(42)`...

Comment: @WaisKamal You mean if we're allowed to use `T` within functions , try to use `T` as more as possible, instead of `new T` ? But those containers variable often are members of class, not temporary variables.

Comment: It's not that you should use `T` and avoid `T*` as much as possible. You should use whatever fits your use case. If you really want a set of pointers, and you don't care whether the *objects behind the pointers* are equal or not, then you should go with `T*`. Otherwise, if you want a set of objects, `T*` won't do the job and will render the set useless.

Comment: As Sean parent advocates, you are better off using value semantics in most cases, ie unordered_set<T>, unless you have a definite reason to choose reference semantics, unordered_set<T*>